# Is there a better option than using FOR XML in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having problems with the Sub query slowing my SQL down quite a lot when I have a lot of records in my table. I was just wondering if a) I'm doing it correctly or b) there's another way of doing what I want.

**[People]**

```
ID  |  Name
------------
 1  |   Bob      
 2  |  Tom
```

**[Pets]**

```
ID  |  Category
----------------
 1  |    Cats
 2  |    Dogs
 3  |    Snakes
```

**[PeoplePets]**

```
PeopleID  |  PetID
-------------------
   1      |    2
   1      |    3
   2      |    1
   2      |    2
```

**QUERY**

```
Select Name,
STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Category FROM PeoplePets PP 
INNER JOIN Pets P ON P.ID=PP.PetID FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS PersonsPets
FROM People
```

**RESULT**

```
Name   |  PersonsPets
---------------------
 Bob   |   Dogs, Snakes
 Tom   |   Cats, Dogs
```

Ok this is a very simplified version of what I have but I was wondering if this is the best or only way to do this?

For one table I have about 30000 Records, when I return the top 300 it can take about 3 seconds when just one Sub query is used, when I add more Sub query's it gets even slower. So in essence I'm just trying to group categories(can be up to 10 different categories) and make a column out of the Data.

Comment: It depends. *Why* are you using this technique? For a report?

Comment: @podiluska Yes I need to output the data to the user.

Comment: And how are you generating this report

Comment: Did you know, `STUFF` is taking a string like `, Dogs, Snakes` and removing the first two characters to remove the leading comma. The bulk of the actual work in this statement to transform a set of values into a comma separated string is done by the `FOR XML` specification. So, are you looking for an alternative for `STUFF` or an alternative for creating a comma separated string?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Oops! Yeah sorry I meant the sub query.

Comment: @podiluska In a Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `stuff()` is not slowing your query down.  The subquery is slowing it down.

This is your query:

```
Select Name,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Category
              FROM PeoplePets PP  INNER JOIN
                   Pets P
                   ON P.ID = PP.PetID
              FOR XML PATH('')
             ), 1, 2, ''
            ) AS PersonsPets
FROM People;
```

I see no correlation to the outer query, so I think it is doing a lot of work -- and producing the same list on every row.  You should first try something like this:

```
Select Name,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Category
              FROM PeoplePets PP  INNER JOIN
                   Pets P
                   ON P.ID = PP.PetID
              WHERE People.ID = PP.PeopleID
              FOR XML PATH('')
             ), 1, 2, ''
            ) AS PersonsPets
FROM People;
```

Second, you should make sure that all the `id` columns are indexed, as well as `PeoplePets(PeopleId, PetId)`.

Comment: Ah yes I missed out the WHERE there. It's been a long Monday :|

Comment: So the answer being No there is no other way to do what I want. Oh well back to the drawing board. Thanks for your replies :)